# Build PHP with pthreads using phpbrew

Tags: php, multithreading, pthreads, php-extension

I want to build and use a custom PHP 5.5.30 on Ubuntu 14 including **pthreads**. But I also want to keep my regular PHP version on the side and switch back and forth between versions whenever I need to.

I lack time, I am not well-versed in building PHP - I have never done any build yet - and so I wanted a solution that would abstract the process in the simplest way possible.

To acheive that it seems using **phpbrew** is the correct way.

So I went and downloaded it, installed a handful of new packages that were apparently required for the build, and finally I launched the following:

```
phpbrew install --name php-5.5.30-zts 5.5.30 +bcmath +cli +ctype +dom +fileinfo +filter +json +mbregex +mbstring +mhash +pcre +pdo +posix +sockets +tokenizer +curl +zts +intl +mysql +pgsql +session
phpbrew use php-5.5.29-zts
```

The build terminates successfully and the newly built php is used by the CLI indeed...

**Before:**

```
me@ubuntu:/$ php -v
PHP 5.5.30-1+deb.sury.org~trusty+1 (cli) (built: Oct  4 2015 16:23:01) 
Copyright (c) 1997-2015 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v2.5.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2015 Zend Technologies
    with Zend OPcache v7.0.6-dev, Copyright (c) 1999-2015, by Zend Technologies

me@ubuntu:/$ php -m
[PHP Modules]
bcmath
bz2
calendar
Core
ctype
curl
date
dba
dom
ereg
exif
fileinfo
filter
ftp
gd
gettext
hash
iconv
intl
json
ldap
libxml
mbstring
mcrypt
memcached
mhash
mysql
mysqli
openssl
pcntl
pcre
PDO
pdo_mysql
pdo_pgsql
pdo_sqlite
pgsql
Phar
posix
readline
Reflection
session
shmop
SimpleXML
soap
sockets
SPL
sqlite3
standard
sysvmsg
sysvsem
sysvshm
tokenizer
wddx
xml
xmlreader
xmlwriter
Zend OPcache
zip
zlib

[Zend Modules]
Zend OPcache
```

**After:**

```
me@ubuntu:/$ php -v
PHP 5.5.30 (cli) (built: Oct  6 2015 11:48:18) 
Copyright (c) 1997-2015 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v2.5.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2015 Zend Technologies

me@ubuntu:/$ php -m
[PHP Modules]
bcmath
Core
ctype
date
dom
ereg
fileinfo
filter
hash
intl
json
libxml
mbstring
mhash
mysql
mysqli
mysqlnd
pcre
PDO
pdo_mysql
pdo_pgsql
pgsql
Phar
posix
Reflection
session
SimpleXML
sockets
SPL
standard
tokenizer
xml
xmlreader
xmlwriter
xsl
zlib

[Zend Modules]
```

BUT, as everyone can see... neither any zts module nor pthreads is listed in the available modules of the generated build.

**So... Questions:**

- Is using phpbrew a good idea in my case?
- **ZTS** is still not in the PHP build, even though I provided the **+zts** variant to phpbrew. What am I doing wrong?

**EDIT:**

I also attempted the following builds to no avail. phpbrew refuses to include zts in its builds:

- `phpbrew install --name php-5.5.30-zts-only 5.5.30 -- --enable-maintainer-zts`
- `phpbrew install --name php-5.5.30-zts-only 5.5.30 +zts -- --enable-maintainer-zts`
- `phpbrew install --name php-5.5.30-zts-only 5.5.30 -- --enable-maintainer-zts --without-readline`

All these are minimal PHP that I want to be built just with zts, for the sake of simplicity. None yields the zts module in the end when calling `php -m`.

Maybe there is some sort of prerequisite? Some package to install maybe?

**EDIT 2:**

I tried the following:

```
phpbrew install 5.5.30 -- --enable-maintainer-zts
phpbrew use php-5.5.30
```

Command `php -i | grep zts` yields the following result:

```
Configure Command =>  './configure'  '--prefix=/home/linux1/.phpbrew/php/php-5.5.30' '--with-config-file-path=/home/linux1/.phpbrew/php/php-5.5.30/etc' '--with-config-file-scan-dir=/home/linux1/.phpbrew/php/php-5.5.30/var/db' '--with-pear=/home/linux1/.phpbrew/php/php-5.5.30/lib/php' '--disable-all' '--enable-session' '--enable-short-tags' '--with-zlib=/usr' '--with-libdir=lib/x86_64-linux-gnu' '--enable-bcmath' '--with-bz2=/usr' '--enable-calendar' '--enable-cli' '--enable-ctype' '--enable-fileinfo' '--enable-filter' '--enable-shmop' '--enable-sysvsem' '--enable-sysvshm' '--enable-sysvmsg' '--enable-json' '--enable-mbregex' '--enable-mbstring' '--with-mhash=/usr' '--enable-pcntl' '--with-pcre-regex' '--with-pcre-dir=/usr' '--enable-pdo' '--enable-phar' '--enable-posix' '--with-readline=/usr' '--enable-sockets' '--enable-tokenizer' '--enable-dom' '--enable-libxml' '--enable-simplexml' '--enable-xml' '--enable-xmlreader' '--enable-xmlwriter' '--with-xsl' '--with-libxml-dir=/usr' '--enable-zip' '--with-openssl=yes' '--enable-maintainer-zts'
extension_dir => /home/linux1/.phpbrew/php/php-5.5.30/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-zts-20121212 => /home/linux1/.phpbrew/php/php-5.5.30/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-zts-20121212
```

Not sure if it helps.

**Conclusion:**

I forgot to install the **pthreads** extension, using the following:

```
phpbrew ext install pthreads 2.0.10
```

Note that you need to use (`phpbrew use php-my-build`) the php version on which you want to install the extension for it to be installed.

Also, note that installing `pthreads` will only work if `+openssl` was included as a variant (if not, trying to call the package remote HTTPS URL will fail).

Comment: So... did you even build the pthreads extension after enabling thread safety? Where's the `pthreads.so`? Did you add it to the `php.ini`? `zts` isn't an extension. It just enables thread safety macro internally in php so that extensions that need thread safety can work.

Comment: zts is not an extension.

Comment: This might help: https://gist.github.com/autaut03/848ca8e70eca4a4e33c3701b4f7b20f4

Comment: and this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20584156/tell-apache-to-use-a-specific-php-version-installed-using-phpbrew

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. Yes, phpbrew is good idea to use for different php version on one pc without need to have several virtual machines.
2. Fot zts you should specify option like this -- --enable-maintainer-zts

Steps:

`1. phpbrew install php-5.5.30 -- --enable-maintainer-zts`
`2. phpbrew use php-5.5.30`
`3. phpbrew ext install pthreads 2.0.10`

- install pthreads version 2 if you are using php5
- phpbrew uses php to download extensions

Comment: OK, I did not even know this was possible! But unfortunately, it still doesn't work. More details in the EDIT above...

Comment: Please try to run it like this`phpbrew install php-5.5.30 -- --enable-maintainer-zts`  

and then `phpbrew use php-5.5.30`  `php -i | grep zts`

Comment: zts is not a module so `php -m` will not help you. It's a compiler option.

Comment: I answered above as an edit. Thanks for your help, btw.

Comment: Ok, now you can install pthreads  `phpbrew ext install pthreads 2.0.10`

Comment: Yes I missed that step! I was aware of that at the start but the ensuing struggle, with problems not described in this question, made me forget.

Comment: +zts always do the work, you don't have to append --enable-maintainer-zts